# Anyway to change a websites markup in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, web-development

When you right click in Chrome and select *Inspect Element*, you can edit the styling and the content. I cannot figure out a way to edit the markup though. Anytime I try to add HTML, it just gets escaped and becomes content.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Right click the element - for example a

```
<p> or <h1>
```

and click edit as html.  This will allow you to edit the html tag, which will be reflected or updated in the page.

BTW this is for development and testing.  Any change must then be committed on the server to persist the result.